# How do I use YouTube API to upload private videos for a product that will be sold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, youtube-api

So I have a video product that I am about to start selling. Once people pay, they will be able to download the videos, or ideally stream it via YouTube.

But...I don't want them to be able to share the link with every Tom, Dick and Harry.

I know that an unlisted video can still be made public, so that won't work for me. But apparently there can be 'private videos' too.

Where can I learn more about this in the API docs? Or what is the best way to approach this? Especially given that I don't want them to have to have a Google+ account.

Ideally, they should be able to login to my app, and watch the embedded videos there. But they should not be able to share the direct YouTube link.

I know they can always share their account info, that's fine...I will do other things to keep track of and monitor that. It's really the anonymous sharing of the YouTube link I am worried about.

Thanks.

Comment: Security through obscurity doesn't work. Seriously, it just doesn't.

Comment: use a dedicated service like wistia...

Comment: @Okuma.Scott it doesn't work for every single case, but for - say the 97% - it probably does. Not saying I am going to go through with it for sure, but I am weighing all my options.

Comment: @apneadiving - their pricing is too expensive (each of their plans has a bandwidth cap - 50GB/mo on the $25 plan....I suspect Vimeo is cheaper).

Comment: @marcamillion I/m not promoting any service in particular, just giving options :)

Comment: As soon as you have a customer that likes your video, nothing will stop them from sharing it. Not to mention sites like [clipconverter.cc](http://www.clipconverter.cc) that make it easy to download youtube videos.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott I know I won't be able to stop that entirely. Not trying to. But at the very least, preventing them from 'easily sharing' a simple URL is an easy way to stop most people. Again...the 97%.

Comment: So where are the videos coming from? If you're uploading them all yourself, and setting them to be private yourself, then it will prevent others from watching it via YouTube, so you'd only have to worry about those who are savvy enough to download the video. However, if you're imagining that users will be contributing videos, then you'll have a problem, because using the YouTube API, uploaded videos go into users' own accounts rather than your own (hence they have to have a G+ account and they can always set the videos to public themselves).

Comment: @jlmcdonald So we will be uploading all the videos ourselves. Ideally, what I want to do is to sell access to our own created videos. I want to use YouTube as a means to offer streaming access - for obvious reasons. So the workflow would be something like this, user logs into myapp.com and buys the video for $10. They can then either download the video to their computer or just watch it in an embed. But I don't want them to be able to share that embedded video with anyone they want to.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [API terms of service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) and check with your legal folks. Specifically, you will want to make sure that your sale of private content uploaded to YouTube is in compliance with #2 in the Terms of Service:

> You agree not to use the YouTube API for any of the following
>   commercial uses unless You obtain YouTube's prior written approval:
>
> the sale of the YouTube API, API Data, YouTube audiovisual content or
>   related services, or access to any of the foregoing;

Comment: Yeh....we aren't `selling YouTube API, API Data or YouTube audiovisual content ore related services, or access to any of the foregoing.` We will no doubt check with them before, if we decide to use them.